# Accessing webpack-dev-server through IP address on mobile phone.

Tags: javascript, ip, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to access my local dev server through my IP address on my phone. I have attempted all of the suggestions that I have found on the internet. Currently I am trying to run the dev server using the following command:

```
webpack-dev-server --port 8000 --hot --host 0.0.0.0
```

I have also tried:

```
webpack-dev-server --port 8000 --hot --host <my_ip_address>
```

I am able to access the dev server while hitting the url: `http://<my_ip_address>:8000`. However, I cannot access it through my mobile phone. It will just hang and hang. I am not receiving any errors either... This is currently what my `webpack.config.js` looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index.jsx'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'react-hot!babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
};
```

I'm sure I am doing something wrong as this is something I have never done before. Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am happy to supply all questions with the information requested to help me through this issue over the weekend. Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you can't connect.  Is your phone on the same wireless network (and therefore subnet) as the computer running webpack?  Could a firewall be interfering?  I know on windows you'd have to setup a custom rule to allow that port out.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not actually sure. I will try and find out.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat So my phone is on the same Subnet as my mac. Now just to make sure that I am approaching this correctly, I am suppose to put in the IP address of the router correct? That way all devices connected to the wi-fi can access my webpack server.

Comment: Externally you would normally setup port forwarding so that when the internet hits a port on your router, it could forward it to an IP on your local network.  Since they're on the same subnet, you should be able to use it's IP address on the local network.  Use [netstat](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117644/how-can-i-list-my-open-network-ports-with-netstat) to make sure you're listening on that local IP.  If that still doesn't work I don't know much about built-in firewalls on the mac, maybe ask your question on that site?

Comment: try to use https://localtunnel.github.io/www/